# breve under letter is not in italics when using \textit

Tags: italic

Because the beginning of the letter is moved a bit to the left when in italics mode, the breve also needs to move to the left,otherwise it is no longer under the letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{semtrans}
\begin{document}
Right position: \U{h}

Wrong position: \textit{\U{h}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Any ideas how to correctly use a breve with italics?

Comment: Do you really want to use that package? It dates back to 1998.

Comment: I am open to suggestions for better ways to create a breve under a letter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The package is old and the definition is missing a `\ltx@sh@ft` that helps correct such positioning.  A more modern definition for the `\U` macro is

```
\newcommand*\U[1]{\oalign{#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-3ex}%
   \vbox to .2ex{\hbox{\u{}}\vss}\hidewidth}}
```

In your own file you will need to enclose this in a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair.  If you are loading the `semtrans` package you will need to use `\renewcommand*` instead.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{semtrans}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\U[1]{\oalign{#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-3ex}%
   \vbox to .2ex{\hbox{\u{}}\vss}\hidewidth}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Upright position: \U{h}

Italic position: \textit{\U{h}}
\end{document}
```

The above is modelled on the definition of the `\b` accent defined in the LaTeX kernel, namely:

```
\DeclareTextCommand{\b}{OT1}[1]
   {\hmode@bgroup\o@lign{\relax#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-3ex}%
     \vbox to.2ex{\hbox{\char22}\vss}\hidewidth}\egroup}
```

You could thus mimic this completely and use

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareTextCommand{\U}{OT1}[1]
  {\hmode@bgroup\o@lign{\relax#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-3ex}%
  \vbox to.2ex{\hbox{\u{}}\vss}\hidewidth}\egroup}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way these days is probably to use xelatex (used for the image here) or lualatex.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

zzz ḫ

\textit{zzz ḫ}

\end{document}
```