# How can I get the accent "breve-below"?

Tags: symbols

Some answers were provided in this question:

[breve under letter is not in italics when using \textit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371759/breve-under-letter-is-not-in-italics-when-using-textit)

It is clear then, that one can make a custom "breve below" macro. However, is the best way, as of today? That is, are there packages that provide more versatile definitions?

Comment: The "best way" nowadays must be using the pre-designed opentype font for these accented-letters, via `fontspec` package with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Stone-Zeng but what if you are just using LaTeX?

Comment: It's impossible to have a perfect support for accented-letters in the *traditional* LaTeX, since the background 8-bit engine tex or pdftex do not really support unicode and opentype.

Comment: @Stone-Zeng ah! I see.

Comment: the answers there look fine to me, the macro for pdftex or using opentype directly, I think this question is really a duplicate as there isn't anything else that can be said really.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree!