# Unicode character U+1E2B

Tags: luatex, unicode

Is there a plain TeX way to to to enter the `unicode U+1E2B` character? Some fonts have this character, for example `Libertine`, and some don't. (I am working with Minion Pro, and it does not have it.) Is there a way to have it for any typeface?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
% U+1E2B
ḫ
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371759/breve-under-letter-is-not-in-italics-when-using-textit is related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minion Pro is well known to lack lots of glyphs.

But it has U+02D8 BREVE and you can define a workaround (note: copy-paste won't work).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\newfontfamily{\test}{Libertinus Serif} % just to see that the correct character is produced

\NewDocumentCommand{\U}{m}{%
  \iffontchar\font"032E
    #1^^^^032e
  \else
    \makeunderbreve{#1}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\makeunderbreve}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vtop{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{##\hfil\cr
      #1\cr
      \noalign{\kern0.15ex}
      \hidewidth^^^^02d8\kern10\fontdimen1\font\hidewidth\cr
      \noalign{\kern-1.2ex}
    }%
  }%
}

\newunicodechar{ḫ}{\U{h}}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% to show the bounding box

\begin{document}

% U+1E2B
ḫ \U{h} \fbox{\U{h}}

{\test ḫ} % this can be copy-pasted (it's in Libertinus Serif)

\textit{aḫa} \textbf{aḫa} \textbf{\textit{aḫa}}

\textit{aha} \textbf{aha} \textbf{\textit{aha}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If U+032E COMBINING BREVE BELOW exists in the current font, it's used, otherwise the breve is put below with an alignment.

Comment: @campa Yes, of course